# How do I use Twitter Bootstrap with Google Maps v3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I want to include Twitter Bootstrap's Tabbed Menus within a Google Maps project that is currently coded completely in javascript.  Because Twitter relies on jQuery, I'm not sure how to use both of them together.

When I try to import jQuery using this `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>` none of my page will render anymore.

I think I might have to use a plugin like [jQuery-ui-map](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/), but it would take too long to manually recode the whole site into jQuery (if that's what I have to do).  Is there a way to import bootstrap and jquery just for the purposes of the tabbed menu, but leave the rest of the site in javascript?

Comment: What research have you done? There are lots of questions about issues with bootstrap and the google maps API v3 (most having to do with css conflicts).  What javascript errors does the console report when "none of my page will render anymore"?

Comment: Where are you loading this in the HEAD? Can you post more code? Bootstrap and Google Maps 3 should play nicely together: http://bootply.com/65763

Comment: My head used to contain `<script type="text/javascript">`, when I replace it with `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>` it no longer renders.   I'm getting the error `load() is not defined` from this part:`<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="load()">`  (load renders the map)

Comment: @Skelly, could you take a look at this: http://dreaminginswahili.com/admin/mapv4.html.  I'm too new to this all, and I'm not sure what search terms to even search.  How would I get jQuery running on this so I can implement a basic twitter bootstraps tab example?  I took a look at your bootply example, but I couldn't find an example of the HTML to load jquery and bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you added the jQuery `<script>` tag in your test page, you *removed* the `<script>` tag that loads your own script. That's why your `load()` function is undefined.

Your current code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js">
</script>

//<![CDATA[

var gmarkers = [];
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
...
```

See how there's no `<script>` tag beginning your own script?

With regard to your question about needing a jQuery plugin to use the Maps API with jQuery, no, you definitely don't need one. I use jQuery and the Maps API together all the time. Consider this: What is a jQuery plugin? JavaScript code! Nothing else. Anything a jQuery plugin does, you can do in your own code.

(I suppose one could imagine that there may be some special bookkeeping that is needed to make jQuery and the Maps API work together, but that just isn't the case. jQuery doesn't care what's inside your map container.)

As @geocodezip mentioned, if you find the map working but odd things happening with the formatting of elements inside the map (e.g. the pan/zoom control gets clipped), check for CSS selectors that affect too many elements, such as:

```
img {
    /* anything here is dangerous! */
}
```

A selector like that will affect images *inside* the map, which should be left alone by your CSS. It doesn't look like you have this problem in your current working test page, just something to be aware of if it happens.

Also, just an unrelated tip, you don't need `type="text/javascript"` on your `<script>` tags, nor `type="text/css"` on your `<style>` tags.

Comment: Hmm.  I changed the code, and I'm still not getting anything.  Could you take a look here: http://dreaminginswahili.com/admin/mapv4.html.  Sorry about all this!

Comment: Actually, I think I fixed it?  There was a random <script> tag at the bottom of the page